# LTspice induction motor model

Tags: motor, ltspice, simulation, review, drive

I'm trying to simulate the dynamic model for induction motor in (alpha, beta) stator axis.

[image: IM]

Results are not correct but I don't know how to fix this issue. How can I fix them?

Code:

```
Version 4
SHEET 1 1544 848
WIRE 96 -224 -160 -224
WIRE 224 -224 176 -224
WIRE 384 -224 304 -224
WIRE 448 -224 384 -224
WIRE 576 -224 528 -224
WIRE 896 -224 656 -224
WIRE -160 -144 -160 -224
WIRE 384 -144 384 -224
WIRE 896 -144 896 -224
WIRE -592 -64 -768 -64
WIRE -368 -64 -512 -64
WIRE -160 32 -160 -64
WIRE 384 32 384 -64
WIRE 384 32 -160 32
WIRE 896 32 896 -64
WIRE 896 32 384 32
WIRE -592 64 -768 64
WIRE -368 64 -368 -64
WIRE -368 64 -512 64
WIRE -320 64 -368 64
WIRE -1440 144 -1440 128
WIRE -1296 144 -1296 128
WIRE -1296 144 -1440 144
WIRE -1168 144 -1168 128
WIRE -1168 144 -1296 144
WIRE 96 144 -160 144
WIRE 224 144 176 144
WIRE 384 144 304 144
WIRE 448 144 384 144
WIRE 576 144 528 144
WIRE 896 144 656 144
WIRE -1296 192 -1296 144
WIRE -592 192 -768 192
WIRE -368 192 -368 64
WIRE -368 192 -512 192
WIRE -160 224 -160 144
WIRE 384 224 384 144
WIRE 896 224 896 144
WIRE -368 240 -368 192
WIRE -160 400 -160 304
WIRE 384 400 384 304
WIRE 384 400 -160 400
WIRE 896 400 896 304
WIRE 896 400 384 400
WIRE 352 496 -160 496
WIRE 896 496 432 496
WIRE -160 544 -160 496
WIRE 896 544 896 496
WIRE -160 704 -160 624
WIRE 896 704 896 624
WIRE 896 704 -160 704
FLAG -1440 48 PHASE
IOPIN -1440 48 In
FLAG -768 64 PHASE_1
IOPIN -768 64 In
FLAG -768 192 PHASE_2
IOPIN -768 192 In
FLAG -768 -64 PHASE
IOPIN -768 -64 In
FLAG -1296 48 PHASE_1
IOPIN -1296 48 In
FLAG -1168 48 PHASE_2
IOPIN -1168 48 In
FLAG -320 64 N
IOPIN -320 64 Out
FLAG -1296 192 N
IOPIN -1296 192 Out
FLAG -368 240 0
SYMBOL bi -592 -64 R270
WINDOW 0 32 40 VTop 2
WINDOW 3 -61 33 VTop 2
SYMATTR InstName i1
SYMATTR Value I=sqrt(2/3)*I(Ls_a)
SYMBOL bv -160 -160 R0
WINDOW 3 -183 127 Left 2
SYMATTR Value V=sqrt(2/3)*V(PHASE,N) - sqrt(1/6)*V(PHASE_1,N) - sqrt(1/6)*V(PHASE_2,N)
SYMATTR InstName Vs_a
SYMBOL bi -592 64 R270
WINDOW 0 32 40 VTop 2
WINDOW 3 -59 -34 VTop 2
SYMATTR InstName i2
SYMATTR Value I=-sqrt(1/6)*I(Ls_a) + sqrt(1/2)*I(Ls_b)
SYMBOL bi -592 192 R270
WINDOW 0 32 40 VTop 2
WINDOW 3 -68 -40 VTop 2
SYMATTR InstName i3
SYMATTR Value I=-sqrt(1/6)*I(Ls_a) - sqrt(1/2)*I(Ls_b)
SYMBOL res 192 -240 R90
WINDOW 0 0 56 VBottom 2
WINDOW 3 32 56 VTop 2
SYMATTR InstName Rs_a
SYMATTR Value {Rs}
SYMBOL ind 208 -208 R270
WINDOW 0 32 56 VTop 2
WINDOW 3 5 56 VBottom 2
SYMATTR InstName Ls_a
SYMATTR Value {Los}
SYMBOL res 544 -240 R90
WINDOW 0 0 56 VBottom 2
WINDOW 3 32 56 VTop 2
SYMATTR InstName Rr_a
SYMATTR Value {Rr}
SYMBOL ind 560 -208 R270
WINDOW 0 32 56 VTop 2
WINDOW 3 5 56 VBottom 2
SYMATTR InstName Lr_a
SYMATTR Value {Lor}
SYMBOL ind 368 -160 R0
SYMATTR InstName Lm_a
SYMATTR Value {Lm}
SYMBOL bv 896 -160 R0
WINDOW 3 -37 113 Left 2
SYMATTR Value V={P}*I(W)*(-{Lor}*I(Lr_b) + {Lm}*I(Ls_b))
SYMATTR InstName BEMF_a
SYMBOL bv -160 208 R0
WINDOW 3 -101 106 Left 2
SYMATTR Value V=sqrt(1/2)*V(PHASE_1,N) - sqrt(1/2)*V(PHASE_2,N)
SYMATTR InstName Vs_b
SYMBOL ind 368 208 R0
SYMATTR InstName Lm_b
SYMATTR Value {Lm}
SYMBOL bv -160 528 R0
WINDOW 3 -350 109 Left 2
SYMATTR Value V={P}*{Lm}*(-I(Ls_b)*I(Lr_a) + I(Ls_a)*I(Lr_b))
SYMATTR InstName Tm
SYMBOL voltage 896 528 R0
WINDOW 3 -151 104 Left 2
WINDOW 123 0 0 Left 0
WINDOW 39 0 0 Left 0
SYMATTR Value PULSE(0 {Cr} {delay_Cr} 1n 1n 10000 10000 10000)
SYMATTR InstName Tr
SYMBOL ind 336 512 R270
WINDOW 0 32 56 VTop 2
WINDOW 3 5 56 VBottom 2
SYMATTR InstName w
SYMATTR Value {Jeq}
SYMATTR SpiceLine Rser=1p
SYMBOL res 192 128 R90
WINDOW 0 0 56 VBottom 2
WINDOW 3 32 56 VTop 2
SYMATTR InstName Rs_b
SYMATTR Value {Rs}
SYMBOL ind 208 160 R270
WINDOW 0 32 56 VTop 2
WINDOW 3 5 56 VBottom 2
SYMATTR InstName Ls_b
SYMATTR Value {Los}
SYMBOL ind 560 160 R270
WINDOW 0 32 56 VTop 2
WINDOW 3 5 56 VBottom 2
SYMATTR InstName Lr_b
SYMATTR Value {Lor}
SYMBOL res 544 128 R90
WINDOW 0 0 56 VBottom 2
WINDOW 3 32 56 VTop 2
SYMATTR InstName Rr_b
SYMATTR Value {Rr}
SYMBOL bv 896 208 R0
WINDOW 3 -80 111 Left 2
SYMATTR Value V= - {P}*I(W)*(-{Lor}*I(Lr_a) + {Lm}*I(Ls_a))
SYMATTR InstName BEMF_b
SYMBOL voltage -1440 32 R0
WINDOW 3 -265 142 Left 2
WINDOW 123 0 0 Left 0
WINDOW 39 0 0 Left 0
SYMATTR Value SINE(0 311.126984 50 0 0 0 0)
SYMATTR InstName v1
SYMBOL voltage -1296 32 R0
WINDOW 3 -197 -150 Left 2
WINDOW 123 0 0 Left 0
WINDOW 39 0 0 Left 0
SYMATTR Value SINE(0 311.126984 50 0 0 120 0)
SYMATTR InstName v2
SYMBOL voltage -1168 32 R0
WINDOW 3 -139 140 Left 2
WINDOW 123 0 0 Left 0
WINDOW 39 0 0 Left 0
SYMATTR Value SINE(0 311.126984 50 0 0 240 0)
SYMATTR InstName V3
TEXT -1480 -384 Left 2 !.param Rs=1 Los=0.1457063504006302 Rr=1.145 Lor=0.14582412505851822 Lm=0.1406929696932355 Jeq=0.18189999999999998 Cr=30 delay_Cr=1 P=2
TEXT -1480 -408 Left 2 !.tran 2 uic
```

EDIT:
I add torque (green) and speed (light blue) plots resulting from simulation:

[image: torquespeedLTspice]

I expect something like this:

[image: torquespeedRef]

Comment: Please show voltage/current graphs and explain why they are not correct.